# Authenticate with Soundcloud without having to open a popup everytime

Tags: soundcloud

I'm having a lot of trouble with connecting to the spotify api on my mobile app.
I have been able to successfully able to get a token with this url:

```
"https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=" + client_id + "&response_type=token&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri) + "&state=" + Spotify.State + "&scope=" + encodeURIComponent(scope) + "&display=" + display;
```

However, this requires the user to click on connect every time they log into the app. Is there not a way to only have them authorize the app once?

I'm assuming that's what **/oauth2/token** is for, but when I change my **&response_type=token** to **&response_type=code** (above) so that I can pass the code into **/oauth2/token** it returns a redirect error (works fine with token).

I've looked around for samples but they are hard to come by. Any help would be greatly appreciated, even a point in the right direction.

I'm referring to the HTTP API guide (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference). I don't want to use a javascript plugin.

Comment: Use a PHP session or a cookie.

Comment: I can't, its a web application, not a website :)

Comment: What about HTML5 APIs or even JavaScript cookie? Can you use them?

Comment: right, but the javascript api will still require the user to navigate to the connect page. I can save the token and any data, but whenever the token expires, to my knowledge you need to call the connect function, which requires a redirect uri, which will navigate away from my app.

Comment: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jbutko/fed567b860a30242e287)

Comment: Thank you! So helpful! That's exactly what I needed.